# IE does not send post data PHP & jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer, jquery

In IE only when sending a post request the POST information is not received by the server.

This works correctly in every other browser tested.

The code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/dashboard/draft/get/data?date=' + new Date(),
    type: 'post',
    data:  {
        'draftid': $.allpro.draftid, 
        'iefix': true
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
        $.allpro.draft.salary_cap = parseInt(response.data.salary_cap)
        $.allpro.draft.salary_remaining = parseInt(response.data.salary_remaining)
        $.allpro.draft.average_spent = response.data.average_spent
        $('#salary_cap').text(response.data.salary_cap)
        $('#salary_remaining').text(response.data.salary_remaining)
        $('#average_spent').text(response.data.average_spent)
        $.each(response.data.drafted, function(_i, _v){
            if (_v.playerid == "0") {
                var id = _v.teamid
                var is_team = 1
            } else {
                var id = _v.playerid
                var is_team = 0
            }
            $.allpro.draft.playerOptions.queue_add(
                id,
                is_team,
                _v.position
            )
        })
        set_requirements(response.data.requirements)
    }
})
```

Doing a `var_dump` on both `$_REQUEST` and `$_POST` show nothing was received.

I've researched this and found many of topics describing a similar issue but none provide a fix ... and as you can see I've already tried to add an additional post field, cache bust and disabling the cache with nothing fixing the problem.

Thanks!

---

Changing this a GET fixes the problem at hand ... but the issue still exists if someone can find a fix.

Comment: Post requests do not cache. Are you sure that the file that holds the JavaScript code is correct?

Comment: Have you used a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see the http request?

Comment: Check your network traffic in IE Developer Tools (F12) and make sure that you are POSTing what you think you are.

Comment: ( the IE dev tool ), it is sending the request body ( draftid=2453&iefix=1 ) but it still is not received - also there are no JS errors and the code is correct

Comment: Try adding an "error" property (in addition to the "success" property) and see if that one gets fired by logging the arguments to the console.

Comment: What does `$.conf.makeURL()` do? Can you replace it with a static url?

Comment: I had this problem and freakishly it only worked when I clicked submit button but when I just clicked enter being on a form's field it always failed. Could you try and confirm what I'm saying by adding submit button to your post and post it with actual button?

Comment: @Ilia Rostovtsev Sounds like a possible fix but this wouldn't go over well since the data must load automatically on page load.

Comment: Make it automatically but only by clicking submit button - add it to your form and make the script submit it by clicking the button.

Comment: There is no submit button to be clicked since there is no form

Comment: What about trying to do this with JSON then?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting you date in your data array

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/dashboard/draft/get/data',

    ...

    data:  {
        'draftid': $.allpro.draftid, 
        'iefix': true,
        'date': new Date()
    },

    ...

})
```

Then with something like firebug, you can look at the post headers to see if there is posts data.

Comment: No go ... problem still persisted